# Why does my historian service on Watson IoT Platform keep becoming "unconfigured"?

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloudant, watson-iot

I have set up a Cloudant NoSQL db service on IBM Cloud to act as the historian database for my Watson IoT Platform service. However, whenever I go to test it, I notice that the status goes from "Configured" to "Not Configured" and nothing gets stored. What may cause this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you set up a Cloudant NoSQL with Watson IoT Platform service, you should get a pop-up (sometimes in a new tab due to browser version) for setup confirmation. After you confirm the setup, everything should be OK. Note that any pop-up blocker might prevent you from seeing the window/tab. Doing this in private browser window can help. Or newly installed browser.

Comment: This was exactly my problem. It is now solved and my device data is getting saved to NoSQL db. Thanks!